# Spring boot Enity failed to add entity with ManyToOne

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, crud, spring-data-rest

I have these entities in my learning project and I could not figure out why I am not able to add an Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@Data
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "department_id")
    @JsonProperty("department_id")
    private Long department_id;

    @Column(name = "department_name")
    @JsonProperty("department_name")
    private String department_name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "office")
@Data
public class Office {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "office_id")
    @JsonProperty("office_id")
    private Long office_id;

    @Column(name = "office_name")
    @JsonProperty("office_name")
    private String office_name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @JsonProperty("employee_id")
    private Long employee_id;

    @Column(name = "employee_name")
    @JsonProperty("employee_name")
    private String employee_name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;

    private Long office_id;
}
```

Using Postman, I send a POST to add an employee in department 'engineer' using the `http://localhost:9096/employee` endpoint generated by Spring Data REST with the following JSON body:

```
{
    "employee_name": "Tim",
    "office_id" : 1,
    "department": {
        "department_id": 1
    }
}
```

I always get an exception: "Column 'department_id' cannot be null".

What should be the correct way to solve this problem?

the complete project can be found at https://github.com/txt8888/sping-mysql-db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Spring Data REST supports embedding the department like that (by using `{ "department_id": 1 }`. By default, if you want to link a resource (eg. a department) to another (eg. an employee), you use the resource link, for example:

```
{
    "employee_name": "Tim",
    "office_id" : 1,
    "department": "http://localhost:9096/departments/1"
}
```

This will create a new employee linked to the department with ID 1. If you want to link the employee to a new department, you likely will have to create the department first, and link it to the employee in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the department_id doesn't exist in your database or your ManyToOne configuration is not properly. So it causes that errors. You can refer to this ManyToOne relationship below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course  implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private Set<Student> students;

    public Course(){

    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private Course course;

    public Student() {

    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
}
```

You can check the working example from the post [Spring Boot JPA One to Many Relationship Mapping](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example.html)

Comment: the 'department_id' does exist in the database.  Please see the resources/schema-mysql.sql

Comment: No, i mean its value not the column name.